# Static Resource in VisualForce Page

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, salesforce1-app, static-resources

I am using google Re captcha in my Visual force Page as below

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" showHeader="false">
    <apex:slds />    
    <html>  
        <head> 
            <script type="text/javascript">
            var verifyCallback = function(response) {
                parent.postMessage("formvalidated", "{!$Site.BaseSecureUrl}");
            }; 
            var onloadCallback = function() {                
                grecaptcha.render('html_element', {
                    'sitekey' :'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
                    'callback' : verifyCallback,
                });
            };
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <form action="?" method="POST">
                <div id="html_element"></div>
                <br/>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" style="display:none"/>
            </form>
            <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit" async="" defer="">
            </script>
        </body>
    </html> 
</apex:page>
```

The above Code working fine.

Now i am trying to Use `Static resource`instead of loading the js URL in the script tag as below.

This is not working

```
<apex:includeScript value="{! $Resource.RecaptchaAPI}"/>
```

i hit this URL `https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js` in browser and saved the js as `recaptchaApi.js` and created the New static Resource with the Name as below

[image]

Can you guide me what I am missing here.

Comment: Are you triggering the callback function?

Comment: Yes, I was triggering the onloadCallback like this `?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By loading the static resource (using the code given below), you are not instructing the VF page specifically what should happen or execute after the JS file is loaded.

```
<apex:includeScript value="{! $Resource.RecaptchaAPI}"/>
```

& `?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit` at the end of your page URL won't do that either (unlike the script tag that has explicit `onload` attribute wired into it). So, you need to update your code as shown below.

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" showHeader="false">
    <apex:slds />
    <apex:includeScript value="{! $Resource.RecaptchaAPI }"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    grecaptcha.ready(function(){
        grecaptcha.render('html_element', {
            'sitekey' :'<Place your site key here>',
            'callback' : verifyCallback,
        });
    });
    
    var verifyCallback = function(response) {
        console.log('inside verifyCallback');
        parent.postMessage("formvalidated", "{!$Site.BaseSecureUrl}");
    };
    </script>
    <form action="?" method="POST">
        <div id="html_element"></div>
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" style="display:none"/>
    </form>
</apex:page>
```

`grecaptcha.ready` function executes after the static resource is loaded and the google recaptcha api is ready. The callback function passed to it should be used to handle rest of the logic.

***Alternate solution:*** You can also do the following (here you can utilize `g-recaptcha` tag attributes such as `data-sitekey` & `data-callback`):

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" showHeader="false">
    <apex:slds />
    <apex:includeScript value="{! $Resource.RecaptchaAPI }"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">    
        function verifyCallback(response) {
            console.log('inside verifyCallback');
            parent.postMessage("formvalidated", "{!$Site.BaseSecureUrl}");
        };
    </script>
    <form action="?" method="POST">
        <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="<Place your site key here>" data-callback="verifyCallback"></div>
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" style="display:none"/>
    </form>
</apex:page>
```